# Open new intent with .setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, android-intent

```
private void readShops() {
    RetailerAdapter retailersAdapter = new RetailerAdapter(
            getApplicationContext(), retailers);
    final ListView listViewRetailers = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewRetailers);
    listViewRetailers.setAdapter(retailersAdapter);

    listViewRetailers
            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView,
                        View childView, int position, long id) {
                    Intent intentNews = new Intent(this, RetailerActivity.class);
                    intentNews.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intentNews);
                }
            });
}
```

It bugs because of Intent(this, RetailerActivity.class);

Intent(null, RetailerActivity.class); fixes it but then the app crashes.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
Intent intentNews = new Intent(this, RetailerActivity.class);
```

with

```
Intent intentNews = new Intent(YourActivityName.this, RetailerActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this in your Intent,use YourActivityName.this or getApplicationContext();